# How the remove the Raspberry Pi Version message after login

Tags: ssh

I've got a cool custom MOTD that shows up after the login. But before my MOTD a line of text with the kernel version and wrong date shows up:

```
login as: pi
pi@pi's password:
Linux raspberrypi 3.6.11-rpi-aufs #1 PREEMPT Sat Sep 7 23:10:27 CEST 2013 armv6l
```

I want to get rid of this line:

```
Linux raspberrypi 3.6.11-rpi-aufs #1 PREEMPT Sat Sep 7 23:10:27 CEST 2013 armv6l
```

I've already tried looking at issue, motd, .profile, etc... But I couldn't find that text anywhere.

Comment: that is the output of 
uname -a
I am not near a Pi at the moment but my guess is the .bashrc or .profile is executing it.

Answer (score 3):

Found it in the `/etc/init.d/motd` file. A shell script that, quote:

> *Short-Description: Create dynamic part of /etc/motd*

You can remove the uname line or the whole file.

Comment: Do you also need to delete `/run/motd.dynamic` which is created by the motd init script?  Or does `/run` get initalized on each boot?

Comment: The proper way would be to use `sudo update-rc.d motd remove` to pull the script out of the init script pool. [manpage](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?sektion=8&query=update-rc.d&apropos=0&manpath=sid&locale=en)

Answer (score 3):

Answer no longer works on Jessie for a (virtual or serial) terminal. It's OK for SSH.
This post explains what's the problem:
https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2014/12/msg00368.html
edit /etc/pam.d/login to remove uname -snrvm then the login message is gone.

Answer (score 0):

1) Execute Command: 
"sudo nano /etc/update-motd.d/10-uname" from the CLI

2) Then hash out (Put a hash before) "uname -snrvm"

3) Save (ctrl x) & exit file)

Job Done!

Comment: FYI, Save in nano is done with `Ctrl-O`. `Ctrl-X` is for Exit, which prompts to save changes if any.